# How to get the urls of all the packages that an application depends on?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, url

I want to install `gnome-shell` package without using `apt` by getting the dependent packages and building them myself so that I won't have to download them the next time I do a fresh install. I want a way to get the urls of the 40+ packages required by `gnome-shell` so that I can `wget` them.

Comment: Not sure what your asking but the independent packages downloads/urls can be found here for 12.04. http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gnome/

Comment: @user107425, I meant, for example if you look [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gnome-shell) `gnome-shell` requires all of those packages e.g `gsettings-desktop-schemas (>= 3.3.2) `. I want to get all of their urls so that I can download them. The same way a package manager does internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is one of the major advantages of using a package manager such as apt (or yum or pacman or ....).

If you do not want to use a package manager, dependency resolution is up you you, you do it manually. You can start with reading the documentation in the source code for `gnome-shell`.

And you are not going to save time as "I won't have to download them the next time", in fact next time you will have to manually resolve all the dependencies and download any and all updated source code for all the depencencies.

You are going to, IMO, have much better luck building from source code on an alternate distro such as gentoo or perhaps arch linux. `emerge` will build from source and resolve dependencies.

Alternately you can look at the LFS documentation for package management:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/pkgmgt.html

IMO, the closest thing to what you might want in Debian/Ubuntu is get-build-deps:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/get-build-deps.1.html

See also: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_management_system

Comment: Looks like too much work. How about the packages downloaded by `apt` through an `apt-get`? Do they get deleted? Maybe there's an option that instructs it to preserve them(big maybe).

Comment: Well, for a large package such as gnome-shell. This is why people use package managers. I personally would use gentoo, but, I am familiar with gentoo so it is easy. gentoo has a steep learning curve. I think get-build-deps is what you want.

Comment: Okay, then, I'll try them out.